# Does a converging sequence of measurable functions necessarily converge towards a measurable function?

Tags: limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Say $f_n\geq0\ \forall n$ are measurable in the sense that $\{x\ :\ f(x)<\alpha\}\in\mathcal M\ \forall\alpha\in\Bbb R$ where $\mathcal M$ is the set of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\Bbb R$. And $f_n\rightarrow f$ 
Is $f :\Bbb R\mapsto\Bbb R$ necessarily a measurable function in the same sense?

Comment: In which norm do you want  $f_n \rightarrow f$ to hold?

Comment: Just pointwise convergence $f_n\rightarrow f\ \iff \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$